# Effective use of Collections.unmodifiable*()

Tags: java, collections

What is more preferable way to expose read-only views of collections when considering efficiency, code readability and other criteria? Does it make any real difference from efficiency point of view  to use `methodA` instead of `methodB` ? Please consider the situation where `list` might be accessed quite often - like in the data model of gui table.

I assume that `Collectionss.umodifiebleList()` creates always a new objects, is this correct?

```
class A{
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    List<Object> listReadOnly = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);

    List<Object> methodA(){
        return listReadOnly;
    }

    List<Object> methodB(){
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: While it goes against the 'use the interface, not the class', when I use the Guava `Immutable*` classes I use that actual class as the field / return type. This makes it very explicit to the user that the collection cannot be mutated.

Comment: B only creates one new object (that wraps the original list) but does not perform a deep copy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, `Collections.unmodifiableList` does create a new object each time - but it's a pretty cheap operation. (It doesn't have much work to do.)

I'm not sure that the data model of a GUI is likely to fetch the collection over and over again - it will obviously fetch the collection and then iterate over it, but that's a different matter.

If it's only fetching a collection each time something prompts the GUI that the data has changed, that's going to be happening *relatively* rarely, I'd expect - not in the "hundreds of thousands of times per second" range where this would really be a bottleneck. I'd expect that whatever code is calling this would probably be doing significantly more work than is involved just in creating the unmodifiable list.

Basically, this feels like a micro-optimization too far, unless you've got evidence that it's causing a problem. As always, you should:

- Define performance requirements
- Write the code in the simplest possible way which meets other requirements
- Write tests to check whether or not you've met your performance requirements
- *If* you don't currently meet those requirements, carefully work out where the bottlenecks are (whether with a profiler or other techniques)
- Fix those bottlenecks with as small a loss of readability as possible
- Lather, rinse, repeat

Answer (score 5):

Don't do `methodA`, because you must maintain state between the lists, which can be tricky in multi-threaded environments, and is a pain even if for a single-threaded environment.

Do `methodB`, and let the JDK sort out efficiency (it's pretty fast).

**Note:** Unless the elements in the list are themselves immutable, methodB is not completely safe, because while *list* might be unmodifiable, its elements may be themselves modified. Consider:

```
List<Date> list = new ArrayList<Date>();
list.add(new Date());
List<Date> dates = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
Date date = dates.get(0);
date.setTime(0);  // The date in the original list has now changed!
```